# iOS: How can I judge the state of UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

As the bellow pics: 
There are 2 states for `UISearchBar`, how can I judge the searchBar's state?

1. 1th

[image: The 1th state]

2. 2th

[image: The 2th state]

Comment: assign delegate to searchBar and listen didBeginEditing,didEndEditing,CancelButtonClicked  etc methods , You have to keep a flag value to populate cellForRow or DidSelectedRow methods to decide from where to get dataValues .Either from search array or from origional array .

Answer (score 2):

On Swift I use this, I'm sure have anything like that to obj-c

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true;
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}
```

Comment: Ohh, there is no 'searchActive'

Comment: YES BECAUSE `SEARCHACTIVE` IS A PROPERTY THAT YOU HAVE TO ADD THAT WILL CONTAIN THE STATE OF THE SEARCH BAR AS YOU HAVE ASKED...

Comment: but i amusing oc, not swift

Answer (score 1):

I think searchBar.isFirstResponder is the property you're looking for.

Comment: I have tried that, searchBar.isFirstResponder are two that state.